# Automatically adding link to related work for tasks?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm using VSTS for task and issue tracking and committing to a git repo hosted on VSTS.

Is there a way to automatically show commits in the 'Development' section of a Task in VSTS without having to manually add it?

In Jenkins I believe there's a plugin where it looks for the commit ID in the commit message to automatically link to the related task in Jira.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options.

- Enter the work item ID in the commit message, like `Implemented a frobulator #1234`.
- Create a branch for the task from **within the work item**, which will automatically associate the branch (and thus all commits to that branch) with the work item.

Comment: First one was exactly the solution that I was looking for